# Phpmyadmin отображение картинок

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql-server, mysql

Не отображаются картинки в phpmyadmin, а так же половина функционала просто не работает.Видимо nginx не отдает статику. Кто сталкивался?

Comment: location /phpmyadmin {        proxy_pass         http://184.222.31.96:81/phpmyadmin/;        allow all;        }не помогло

Comment: Давайте нам сюда конфиг нгинкса под домен. Посмотрим...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас nginx (фронт-енд) + apache (бэк-енд), то возможно, что подойдет такой вариант:

```
server {    listen 80;    server_name username.com www.username.com;    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;    location / {        root /home/username/public_html;        index   index.php index.html index.htm;    }    error_page 404 /404.php;    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;    location = /50x.html {        root /var/www/nginx-default;    }    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/ {        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    }    location ~ .php$ {        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    }    location ~ /$ {        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    }    location ~ /.ht {        deny all;    }}
```

Суть такова, что Nginx занимается всем, кроме заканчивающихся на ".php", заканчивающихся на "/" и начинающихся с "/phpmyadmin/". Это он отдает в apache, а статикой занимается сам.

Answer (score 1):

```
    location /phpMyAdmin {           root /var/www/html/;           index index.php index.html index.htm;           location ~ ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.php)$ {                   try_files $uri =404;                   proxy_pass http://184.222.31.96:81/phpmyadmin/;           }           location ~* ^/phpMyAdmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {                   root /var/www/html/;           }    }    location /phpmyadmin {           rewrite ^/* /phpMyAdmin last;    }    location /pma {           rewrite ^/* /phpMyAdmin last;    }
```